# Java calendar similar to Python datetime

Tags: java, python, datetime, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm new to Java and have to translate a Python script using `datetime` to a Java program. How do I create a `Calendar` object in Java, that can have any possible year, month and day, e.g. 03.12.2050. I have to be able to add a certain amount of days to it - for example, 03.12.2050 + 29 days to get 01.01.2051 - How can I do that in Java?

It would be useful, but not necessary if the calendar class could represent Julian dates too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the [java.time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (introduced in Java 8) - it is much better and easier to use than the legacy Calendar API.

Applied to your example, it would look like:

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(2050, 12, 3);
LocalDate d2 = d1.plusDays(29); // 2051-01-01
```

It also supports [Julian days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404159/calculate-modified-julian-day-in-jsr-310), but not the Julian calendar, which is available in [threeten-extras](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/chrono/JulianChronology.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)?

```
GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar(12,12,1994);
g.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR,2);
```

Comment: for some reason i didnt find this ... thank you thats all i need ... the documentation is very hard to read... how do i return the month of this date? And is there a possibilaty to create a julian date?

Comment: You can use the getTime() method which returns a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object. From there you can extract days, month, or year (but theses are deprecated methods)

Comment: 'code'a= new GregorianCalendar(2000,11,12);
        a.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,30);
        System.out.println(a.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println(a.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));
        System.out.println(a.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));'code' why does the change between months not work? (or only sometimes)